# Change the way ANSYS workbench appears for version 18.2

Tags: workbench, ansys

I have a very specific question regarding ANSYS boot up and use.

I am not very familiar with ANSYS, but I have used the workbench enough before to be familiar with it. So when I went to open the workbench I was surprised to see this.
[image: undesired GUI]
[image: second desired GUI]
I am used to something that looks more like this second picture. I am using ANSYS 18.2, and that is the same version on all computers my students will be using in class. However, I don't have any idea how to change it to look like the second and cannot access ANSYS help since I don't manage the license and non of the student lab techs know anything about ANSYS. I can't effectively teach my students ANSYS if workbench GUI looks so different.

**Can someone with more experience point me to the right setting or options to do this.**

Answer (score 0):

So apparently, this is the answer.

The first screenshot is technically the app called AIM (despite the fact that if you zoom in to the top left it says workbench). I was able to just type in "workbench" in the windows search bar and the correct app popped up.